# ESX: allowing users to snapshot VMs without vSphere Client Access

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, snapshot

I am using ESX (latest free version 5.X) to host multiple VMs (mainly Windows with some Linux).  Users will have control of these VMs and should be able to snapshot them, however I don't want to deal with giving any access to the actual ESX host.  I am considering using the Powershell plugin for VMWare and creating a script with a web front end to allow users to create snapshots from an internal web page.  Is there any easier way?  What would be the best practice here?

Comment: ESXi's API is not available in the free version. You won't be able to do this with the API.

Comment: Meaning the powershell script will not even be an option?

Comment: You could potentially work up something by executing a script to the ESX host console, but since you have to expose your root credentials to the script it could be very insecure. See [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006847)

Comment: What's wrong with giving them rights to only those VMs they need and only to create snapshots?  Even with the client they won't be able to do anything else on the host.

Comment: It is just a PITA from a management perspective as there is a fairly large number of users and VMs to manage, but I am fine letting anyone create a snapshot.  We are using local authentication on the ESX host, so I would have to manually add each person to a restricted group.  Being able to remotely create snapshots seems easier.